# Algebraic Manipulation with Cube Roots

Tags: cubics

Let $a,$ $b,$ $c$ be the real roots of $x^3 - 4x^2 - 32x + 17 = 0.$ Solve for $x$ in $$\sqrt[3]{x - a} + \sqrt[3]{x - b} + \sqrt[3]{x - c} = 0.$$

We probably have to manipulate the $\sqrt[3]{x - a} + \sqrt[3]{x - b} + \sqrt[3]{x - c}$ into something more convenient, so we can actually use it to solve the problem. The first thing I tried was cubing the equation; I quit midway through realizing it was a bad idea (It was really messy.)

Next, I got the stupid idea of trying to actually solve the cubic. I got nowhere. (What I was hoping for were some nice solutions for $x.$)

Now, I'm stuck. Help? Thanks!

Comment: Possibly use a well known (in contest math, at least) factorization of $A^3 + B^3 + C^3 - 3ABC,$ such as is done in [Answer 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2456169/13130) and in [Answer 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/778814/13130).

Comment: @Fleccerd I see that you proposed many questions in the past, but never accepted an answer

Comment: @enzotib that is false.

Comment: @Fleccerd how can you say that? It is on your profile page, everybody can see. I respect your will to not accept answers, but please don't deny evidence

Comment: @Fleccerd In the remote case you are not aware, by "accepting" the answer we mean clicking on the "tick / check mark" next to an answer so that it becomes green. This is used to mark  one of the answers as the "accepted" one, the one which in your opinion answers the question better. You can only accept one answer for each question. You seem to have never done this in the past, according to your profile. If you browse the site, you'll notice these green ticks on many questions (not all, but most).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Elevating to third power we get
$$
3 \left[x+\left(\sqrt[3]{x-a}+\sqrt[3]{x-b}\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{x-a}+\sqrt[3]{x-c}\right) \left(\sqrt[3]{x-b}+\sqrt[3]{x-c}\right)\right]-(a+b+c)=0
$$
using the original equation gives
$$
3 \left[x-\sqrt[3]{x-a}\sqrt[3]{x-b}\sqrt[3]{x-c}\right]-(a+b+c)=0\\
3 \left[x-\sqrt[3]{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}\right]-(a+b+c)=0\\
$$
but
$$
a+b+c=4\\
(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)=x^3-4x^2-32x+17
$$
so the equation becomes
$$
3 \left[x-\sqrt[3]{x^3-4x^2-32x+17}\right]-4=0\\
$$
and isolating the cube root and elevating again to the third power
$$
x^3-4x^2-32x+17=\left(x-\frac{4}{3}\right)^3\\
$$
simplifying we get
$$
1008x=523\quad\implies\quad x_0=\frac{523}{1008}
$$
Be aware that the cube root is intended to be defined on the whole $\mathbb{R},$ otherwise no real solution would exist, given that one of $x_0-a,x_0-b,x_0-c$ is negative.

Comment: Very good..... +1

Comment: OMG THAT IS SO CLEVER

thank you so much!

Comment: I have attempted to give a different solution, accompanied by graphical representations that help (so I think) in the understanding of this very special question...

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that there exists a slightly less "magic wand" solution.

Let $p(x)=x^3 - 4x^2 - 32x + 17.$

We will use later on the fact that the sum of its roots is $4$ (one of Vieta's formulas).

Let us give the names $g(x), A, B, C$ in the following expression :

$$g(x)=\underbrace{\sqrt[3]{x-a}}_A+\underbrace{\sqrt[3]{x-b}}_B+\underbrace{\sqrt[3]{x-c}}_C$$

Our hypothesis is that :

$$A+B+C=0\tag{1}$$

Now, consider classical identity (as advised by @Dave L. Renfro) :

$$A^3+B^3+C^3-3ABC=(A+B+C)\tfrac12\underbrace{((A-B)^2+(B-C)^2+(C-A)^2)}_{E}$$

Identity (1) implies

$$A^3+B^3+C^3-3ABC=0$$

Otherwise said :

$$(x-a)+(x-b)+(x-c)=3\sqrt[3]{(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)}$$

$$3x-(a+b+c)=3\sqrt[3]{p(x)}$$

$$(x-\tfrac43)^3=p(x)$$

Expanding the LHS, a big simplification occurs, leaving a first degree equation... whose root $x=\frac{523}{1008}\approx 0.51885$ is the looked-for value.

Remark : I have said upwards : "identity (1) implies" ; in fact a closer look shows that it is an "equivalence" because expression $E$ cannot be zero unless $A=B=C$ which cannot be the case.

[image]

*Fig. 1 : On the same figure, a plot of functions $p$ (in fact $\frac{1}{20}p$) and $q$. Please note the inflection points of $q$ whose abscissas are the roots $\approx -4.3194676,\ \ 0.50354521,\ \ 7.8159224$ of $f$.*

SAGE program for the generation of the figure (its interest is to show how the cubic root function $r3$ has to be re-defined)

> ```
> var('x')
> def r3(x) :
>   if x > 0:
>   y = (x)^(1/3)
> else:
>   y = -(-x)^(1/3)
> return y
> #s=solve(x^3 - 4*x^2 - 32*x + 17==0,x)
> def g(x) :
>   z = r3(x-0.50354521)+r3(x+4.3194676)+r3(x-7.8159224)
> return z
> G1=plot(0.05*(x^3 - 4*x^2 - 32*x + 17),-6,9,color='red');
> G2=plot(g,-6,9);
> G1+G2
> ```